# Image of annulus under flow of vector field and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm studying Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds, in chapter 9 he introduces integral curves and vector flows, I'm using the following definitions.
**Definition:** Let M be a manifold a **flow domain** for M is an open subset D $\subset \mathbb{R} \times M $ such that $\forall p \in M$ $D^{(p)}= \{ t\in \mathbb{R} | (t,p) \in D\} \ $ is an open interval containing $0$.
**Definition:** Let M be a manifold a **flow** on M is a continuous map $\theta : D \to M$ where D is a flow domain such that $\theta$ satisfies the following group laws
$\bullet \forall p \in M \ \  \theta(0, p) = p$ 
$\bullet \forall s\in D^{(p)}$ and $t \in D^{(\theta(s,p))}$ such that $s+t \in D^{(p)}$ $$ \theta(t, \theta(s,p))= \theta (s+t, p)$$

We also defined $\theta_t(p) = \theta^{(p)}(t) = \theta(t,p)$ and $M_t=\{p\in M| (t,p) \in D\}$

I'm also familiar with the fundamental theorem of flows

I'm asked to find the flow of the vector field $V(z)=\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$ in the manifold $\mathbb{C}-0$ and the image of $\theta_t(A)$ for $t>0$ and A is the annulus $1<|z|<2$.

I realized that I needed to find all integral curves starting at arbitrary points $(x_0, y_0) $ in M and for that I solved the system of differential equations
\begin{cases}
x'(t) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
y'(t)= \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\\
x(0)= x_0\\
y(0)=y_0
\end{cases}
where $x_0, y_0$ can't be both $0$, I solved the system using substitution and separable equations and found the most general solution to be
$$\theta^{(x_0,y_0)}(t) = (\sqrt{\frac{2t}{(y_0/x_0)^2 + 1}+ x_0^2}) \ (\text{sgn}(x_0), \frac{y_0}{|x_0|})$$ for $t>-(1/2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)$ when $x_0 \neq 0$

and $$\theta^{(0,y_0)}(t) = (\sqrt{2t + y_0^2})(0, \text{sgn}(y_0))$$

for $t>\frac{-y_0^2}{2}$

All this already gives me the flow of the vector field because of the uniqueness of the maximal integral curves and I know how the domain flow looks like $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a paraboloid and the $z$ axis.

My question is, are the integral curves that I found okey ? and how do I find $\theta_t(A)$ for $t>0$? I'm stuck there and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Prospective integral curves can always be checked by verifying whether or not $\theta'(t) = V(\theta(t))$. <> Here, the field is radially symmetric so the integral curves have radial symmetry, i.e., $\theta^{(x_{0}, y_{0})}(t) = (x_{0},y_{0})f^{(x_{0}, y_{0})}(t)$ for some function $f^{(x_{0}, y_{0})}$.